Web Socket connection failed
On my website i am using Django, the WebSocket works fine on localhost but when i push it to VPS (Virtual private server) i get the error of WebSocket connection to wss://domain_name/ws/admin/pending/products/ failed.
this is my asgi.py:
import os

import django
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

import api.routing

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Naviguih_backend.settings")
django.setup()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(URLRouter(api.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)),
    }
)

and my routing.py:
from django.urls import path

from .consumers import AdminNotificationConsumer, NotificationConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path("ws/notifications/", NotificationConsumer.as_asgi()),
    path("ws/admin/pending/products/", AdminNotificationConsumer.as_asgi()),
]

I read some solutions that says you need to configure the Nginx to forward port and here is my configuration:
server {
    server_name domain_name;
    client_max_body_size 25M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /ws/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = domain_name) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name domain_name;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

and then i try it i get the same issue.

Which application server are you using to host the ASGI application?

@AKX i use Daphne

Do its logs say anything?

@AKX i have these as logs for my server : Not Found: /ws/admin/pending/products/ 2024-10-20 07:42:25,792 WARNING  Not Found: /ws/admin/pending/products/
